# How to activate second ActionListener if the first one is still busy?

Tags: java

This is my program. I don´t understand, why the second ActionListener of btnStop doesn´t work. I start a while-loop with the btnStart. But I can´t stop it. Can somebody explain me why?

public class ActionFrame extends JFrame {

```
JButton btnStart = new JButton("Start");
JButton btnStop = new JButton("Stop");
boolean flag = false;

public ActionFrame() {
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    setSize(600, 600);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
    add(btnStart);
    add(btnStop);

    btnStart.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            flag = true;
            System.out.println("Start waitForFlag()");
            waitForFlag();
        }
    });

    btnStop.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            flag = false;
        }
    });
}

public void waitForFlag() {
    while (flag) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
            System.out.println("Test");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It looks like you're over-complicating this with two listeners. Best to have one listener and set/refer to an external variable to determine what course of action to take eg variable is a time.
Also, you should probably read up about background threads. Merely changing the flag won't interrupt the thread.

Answer (score 0):

Read [the tutorial on Swing concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html).

All swing event listeners are invoked in a single thread, the event dispatch thread. If you start an infinite loop in one of them, you prevent any other listener to be called, and you prevent the UI to repaint itself, freezing the whole UI.

Event listeners must NOT do long-lasting tasks. Those should be done in a separate thread.